# Angular 2 application deployment using WiX toolset

Tags: angularjs, angular, wix

We are working on an application being migrated to Angular 2 from silverlight. As application has several modules, sudden migration is not possible. So we have decided to move 2-3 modules at once into angular 2 keeping other modules into silverlight.

We are using WiX Toolset for making executable of our application. Can I use WiX Toolset for making executable of angular 2 application as well?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, YES.

```
The WiX command-line build tools work with any automated build system. Also, MSBuild is supported from the command line...
```

So MSBuild is supported, you could package an Angular 2 app then.

Comment: thanks for your inputs, I have started including angular 2 files in my wix setup.
I have one more question, as I am going angular2 + Silverlight way, can you suggest a tool for testing. We have explored and find that most of the people are recommending Protractor.